# A riddle to twiddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I am light but strong,
>   Sometimes I am long
>   I can write but cant read
>   To humans I don't belong
>   Flight is guaranteed
>
> I will help you sleep
>   Even more deep
>   Or in your hat
>   I might not be cheap
>   You could find me in a cat

**What am I?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> a feather.

I am light but strong,

> Feathers are lightweight,
> but sturdy enough to support the weight of large flying birds.

Sometimes I am long

> Some feathers (e.g., the tail feathers of peacocks, parrots and parakeets)
> are quite long.

I can write but can't read

> Feathers can be made into quill pens, which are writing implements,
> but they have no ability to read.

To humans I don't belong

> Feathers belong to birds, not to humans.

Flight is guaranteed

> Presumably this refers to the fact
> that feathers contribute to birds' ability to fly,
> but "guaranteed" seems inappropriate,
> since some birds (that have feathers) cannot fly.

I will help you sleep
Even more deep

> Feathers are used in pillows.

Or in your hat

> Feathers are used as decorations in hats.

I might not be cheap

> Some feathers (especially long ones; see above) may be expensive.

You could find me in a cat

> Cats eat birds.  While I imagine that they try to avoid eating the feathers,
> they probably cannot avoid doing so occasionally.

Comment: Correct, well done

Comment: My guess of helium was alright, but your fits better with the hat clue.

Comment: I wouldn't doubt that someone with the username @PeregrineRook could solve this one.

Comment: Yeah; it occurred to me that, if I had missed this, I would have had to give up my name.    :-)    ⁠

Answer (score 3):

I think you are:

> Helium

I am light but strong

> Helium is lighter than air, and in large quantities can be strong enough to lift heavy objects

Sometimes I am long

> Helium is used in balloons, twisting balloons can be long and thin

I can write but cant read

> Twisting balloons can create letters?

To humans I don't belong

> Helium has been around around forever, so it doesn't belong to us

Flight is guarenteed

> Helium Balloons can float

I will help you sleep, Even more deep

> Helium has been used in anaesthesia, which is a deeper form of sleep

Or in your hat

> Helium is in the air, so it could be in your hat

I might not be cheap

> Helium has been being used a lot and we could have a shortage, so the value is always rising

You could find me in a cat

> Air contains a small amount of helium, so it can be within the cat's lungs

Comment: I opened about 5 tabs to research the uses of helium. It was worth it though.

Comment: Nice idea, but incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Some other interesting one that would also work:

> Aluminium

I am light but strong,

> Aluminium is indeed light and strong

Sometimes I am long

> you can make long things with it (wires, poles, &c)

I can write but cant read

> You can make pens with aluminium

To humans I don't belong

> It is something that will poison humans, so why would it be in humans?

Flight is guarenteed

> Before composites, [many airplanes](https://www.quora.com/What-materials-are-planes-typically-made-of-and-why) were made with aluminium.

I will help you sleep
Even more deep

> Same with the humans part. You could die from aluminium poisoning.

Or in your hat

> Helmets

I might not be cheap

> With alloys, it could be expensive.

You could find me in a cat

> If the cat was being stupid.